# Windows 7, running 3 apps in sequence with delays on boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

On boot I need to run the 3 following processes sequentially, and optionally define a delay between each

1- launch a node js server
2- launch a browser (shortcut)

3- launch an application

In Windows 7, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called startup.vbs in notepad and paste this code into it. Run the file on startup (put a shortcut in your startup folder).

I'm not able to properly test the node.js server line myself. Let me know how it goes.

```vb
Dim objWshShell, ls, lc, la
set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ls = objWshShell.Run("cmd /k cd C:\the\path\to\your\server && node myServer.js", 0, false)
WScript.Sleep 1000 'Time in milliseconds

lc = objWshShell.Run("chrome localhost:8080", 1, false)
WScript.Sleep 1000 'Time in milliseconds

la = objWshShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe""")
set objWshShell = nothing
```

Change the applications and delays to those that you need

Comment: thanks will try, but what about non executables, like a node server which i usually run via the command console? i.e. $node app

Comment: I edited it to include a node.js line, thanks to [Jeremythuff on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16493653/2383361), but I'm not able to test it. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Line4 Char 74- Cannot use a parentheses when calling a Sub

Comment: shouldn't Set be set?  as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455655/starting-and-stopping-node-js-server-from-windows-batch-file

Comment: I modified the code to basically carbon copy Jeremythuff's. I know the old code worked for what I could test, but couldn't test the js node, so I'm not sure what nuance I was missing there. Try the new code and let me know. And the capitalization on the set shouldn't matter.

Comment: thanks...only change i had to make was put the delay  in brackets WScript.Sleep(1000)

Comment: Really? Strange. I wonder why that is? Works for me.